# How to get R to recognize double digit numbers when setting an extraction of file names when compiling?

Tags: r, types, extract

I have a bunch of files I'm trying to compile and extract column values from the file names. The files all have the following format: D#Q##. However, with the way I have written the code, R is not recognizing the double digit numbers since they aren't integers. Is there a way around this where I can get R to recognize just the numbers as integers but still keep the Q in front?

```
str_extract(allnames[, ncol(allnames)], pattern = "Q[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]") #extract the block number from the file name
test$depth = str_extract(allnames[, ncol(allnames)], pattern = "D[0-3]") #extract the depth from the file name and add as a column
test$quadrat = str_extract(allnames[, ncol(allnames)], pattern = "Q[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]") #extract quadrat number
```

Comment: `pattern = "Q[0-9]{2}"` will match Q followed by exactly 2 digits. `"Q[0-9]{1,2}"` will match Q followed by 1 or 2 digits. `"Q[0-9]+"` will match Q followed by one or more digits. `"Q[0-9]*"` will match Q followed by 0 or more digits. You can [read more about regex quantifiers here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/regex/quantifiers).

Comment: @GregorThomas I had actually tried doing this previously and still only got Q 1-9... none of my double digit files are being recognized. Is there anything else that could be causing this?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding `[`-based character groups. Your `Q[1,2,3,...,15]` is not going to find `Q1` through `Q15`, it will find `Q1` through `Q9` as well as `Q,` (queue and comma). Everything inside the `[`/`]` brackets create a class. Your pattern is interpreted as `Q[0-9.]`, meaning "letter Q followed by a digit or a comma". Perhaps you mean `Q(1|2|3|4|...|14|15)`, which means _exactly_ `Q1` through `Q15`, though even then the pattern can be "defeated" since `Q23` (if present) will be matched as `Q2` (since `23` is not in the `(`-grouping of `|`-separated patterns.

Comment: We can help even more if you provide sample file names.

Comment: @r2evans I think I understand that. My list was my final attempt at trying to get something to work. I guess I should've listed everything else I attempted. I'm trying to get it to not interpret it as Q[0-9]. I've tried Q[0-9]+ and Q[0-9]{1,2} to get it to read double digits and I just tried your suggestion of using | instead of commas. I only have discrete numbers of Q1-Q15. Ex. filenames: D3Q2, D1Q5, D0Q10, D1Q15, D1Q14, etc.

Comment: If you make your example file names in valid R syntax, we can test. For example, if I define `x = c("D3Q2", "D1Q5", "D0Q10", "D1Q15", "D1Q14")` you can copy/paste that into R and get the same `x` as me. And if I then run `stringr::str_extract(x, pattern = "Q[0-9]+")` I get a nice result. Please make your example reproducible like that.  The `dput()` function can help here, `dput(allnames[1:10, ncol(allnames)])` will make copy/pasteable code to reproduce the first 10 items of that last column of `allnames`.